# Vhs capture: 720x576 or less?

Tags: vhs

On many forum and sites people say that you can capture with resolution of 720x576. But many other replies is too high resolution and is better to capture at 512x384 or similar. Someone know what is the max original resolution of a vhs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to capture at 640x480. VHS uses interlaced video, so the recorded content provides half the lines every 1/30th of a second. The effective resolution is horribly low, 352x240.

Have a look at [VHS capture DIVX information](http://www.divx-digest.com/articles/vhs_capture.html), which seems to discuss all the issues.

Regardless of the workflow you use, be sure your de-interlacer is high-quality or the output will suffer greatly.

Comment: One field (half the scan lines) is transmitted at *twice* the frame rate, so every 1/60th of a second.

Comment: This assumes NTSC; OP may have PAL material.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. My setup is kind of peculiar, but works extremely well.

Regular (decent, but consumer) VHS deck.

SCART2HDMI box. The neat thing about these, is that they usually include a Time Base Corrector (TBC) and thus are much better than the regular USB dongles.

Then, I used a cheap HDMI capture card for about $15 which takes the HDMI. It captures in 1280x720, which on the face of it looks like overkill. However, because it is so cheap, it only capture bad MJPEG format, which is blocky. Downscaled to for instance 720x576 (for PAL VHS) it looks very very good. The blockiness goes away.

Should I capture at 720x576, the MJPEG compression shows as blocks.